# Flex Datagrid - how to do multiple selection programmatically (column only)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, flash-builder

I have a datagrid and I'm trying to allow the user to click a button to select a specific column of my dataGrid. I'm trying to select a specific column so that that the user can then copy and paste it into excel. I'm able to selects all columns and row showing, but only want a specific coloumn. If anyone has any suggestions, that would be awesome - Thanks!

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            var indexArr:Array = [];

            for(var i:int=0; i<budgetGrid.dataProvider.length; i++) {
                indexArr.push(i);
            }
            budgetGrid.selectedIndices= indexArr;

        }
```

Comment: You are using Flex 3 or 4? Please make sure you provide that information before hand.

Comment: I'm sorry - I'll be sure to include it in my future posts! I'm using flex 4. I'll try your solution and circle back. Thanks a ton!!

Comment: It should work with Flex 4 as well just need to make some changes here and there.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works perfectly fine. The moment you click on header of any of the column of `DataGrid` it will also set selection color to all the items. Then you can click on button to select all the items in the column and click on another button to print them. If you click again on selected column it will remove the background selection colour and will also nullify the selected column. I am pasting the complete code which you can easily run in Flex. It is using Halo `Datagrid`. You can do some clean-up as per your need.

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
                creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)"
                >
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
            import mx.controls.Alert;
            import mx.controls.dataGridClasses.DataGridColumn;
            import mx.events.DataGridEvent;
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;

            var selectedColumnItems:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
            var selectedColumn:DataGridColumn;
            var selectedColor:String ="0x7FCEFF";

            protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(selectedColumn) {
                    selectedColumnItems.removeAll();
                    for each(var obj:Object in dg.dataProvider) {
                        selectedColumnItems.addItem(obj[selectedColumn.dataField]); 
                    }
                }
            }

            protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
            {
                if(selectedColumn){
                    for each(var obj:String in selectedColumnItems) {
                        Alert.show(obj);
                    }
                }
            }

            protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                dg.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.HEADER_RELEASE, selectColumn);

            }
            private function selectColumn(event:DataGridEvent):void 
            {
                //Set some background color to give the impression that the column is selected.
                var existingColor:String = dg.columns[event.columnIndex].getStyle("backgroundColor");
                if(existingColor == null ){
                    selectedColumn = dg.columns[event.columnIndex];
                    selectedColumn.setStyle("backgroundColor", "0x7FCEFF");
                } 
                else 
                {
                    selectedColumn = null;
                    dg.columns[event.columnIndex].setStyle("backgroundColor", null);
                }
                event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            }

        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:VBox width="100%">
        <mx:DataGrid id="dg">
            <mx:dataProvider>
                <mx:Array>
                    <mx:Object age="24" sex="f" name="Susan" joinDate="{new Date(2007, 5, 15)}" />
                    <mx:Object age="36" sex="f" name="Ashley" joinDate="{new Date(1998, 7, 20)}" />
                    <mx:Object age="24" sex="f" name="Jennifer" joinDate="{new Date(2001, 3, 24)}" />
                    <mx:Object age="19" sex="f" name="Emma" joinDate="{new Date(2002, 3, 24)}" />
                    <mx:Object age="44" sex="f" name="Carol" joinDate="{new Date(1999, 9, 16)}" />
                </mx:Array>
            </mx:dataProvider>
        </mx:DataGrid>
        <mx:Button label="Copy Selected Column" click="button1_clickHandler(event)"/>
        <mx:Button label="Print Selection" click="button2_clickHandler(event)"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:Application>
```

Comment: The print works. However, when I try copy and paste i get [Bindable] public